# News plugin for ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

Our company has live news features in the linked.com panel on the right-hand side (" features in the news"). Is there any plugin for ASP.NET that will automatically gather and display company news? I don't want to either parse our news from a publish resource, nor have to manually update the website code -- ie. just a plug-in that works.

Comment: Gather from where? Display where?

Comment: I believe the linkedin.com news is gathers from Google News. And features, obviously, on their website. I'm looking for the same...

Answer (score 2):

If your news had an RSS feed it would make it really easy to parse that onto a page.

Does it?